# How can I compute the difference in consecutive rows for multiple columns?

Tags: r

I have a df consisting of daily returns for various maturities. The first column consists of dates and the next 12 are maturities. I want to create a new df that calculates the difference in consecutive daily rates. Not sure where to start.

[image]

Comment: Try with `diff(df[-1])`

Answer (score 2):

With `multiple` columns, `diff` can applied

```
rbind(0, diff(as.matrix(df[-1])))
```

---

Or we can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate_at(vars(-Date), ~ . - lag(.))
```

---

Reproducible example

```
diff(as.matrix(head(mtcars)))
```

Answer (score 2):

In the future try to refrain just providing a picture and provide a [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)!

Here is one way to get what you're looking for:

```
df <- 
  data.frame(
    dates= c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-03"),
    original_numbers = c(1,2,3)
  )

df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    difference = original_numbers - lag(original_numbers)
    )
```